# write one specific formula in python

Tags: python, math

I have a question, everyone knows how can I write this formula with python?

[image]

Comment: @Ch3steR and then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def formula(rx, cx, wx, cub, wub):
    return rx * min(cub/cx, (wub/wx) ** 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those square brackets are just nested parentheses,

```py
def r(x):
    # ???

def c(x):
    # ???

def w(x):
    # ???

def f(x):
    return r(x) * min(c_ub / c(x), (w_ub / w(x)) ** 3)
```